# C++ communication with arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-communication

Working on communication between arduino and PC (Win 7) in c++.  No problem creating communication or  just simple sending or receiving data with WriteFile and ReadFile. But when I want to somehow "coordinate" communication, I have problem.
The goal is in for cycle (simplistic):

```
for (int i=0; i < 310; i++)
{
    com->send(micro[i]);
}
```

call procedure, that should send data to arduino, and now just receive back that data.

```
int send(string input)
{
    DWORD written, read;
    char buffer[7] = {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};
    input.append("$");


    if(!WriteFile(this->comMotor, input.c_str(), input.size(), &written, NULL))
        qDebug() << "WriteFile failed"

    if(written != input.c_str())
        qDebug() << "write problem";


    do
    {
        if(!ReadFile(this->comMotor, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &read, NULL))
            qDebug() << "ReadFile failed";
        if (read)
            qDebug() << "buffer: " << buffer;
    }while(!read);
```

I expected it will send *input* to arduino and then receive string like *input* without $ back. But it doesn't work.. it's sometimes reading "nothing" or really delayed, what I didn't expecting using active waiting for response. I think next sended string should wait for response, but apparently it doesn't.

for completion, here is code in arduino:

```
void loop() 
{ 
    if (Serial.available())  
    {
        char c = Serial.read();
        if (c == '$') 
        {
            if (readString.length() >0) 
            {
                Serial.println(readString); //prints string to serial port out
                int n = readString.toInt();  //convert readString into a number
            }

            readString=""; //clears variable for new input
        } 
        else 
        {     
            readString += c; //makes the string readString
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice how to solve this, or idea what I'm doing wrong? Thank you a lot.

EDIT: edited code

Comment: `sizeof(input.c_str())` is probably your problem, you want `input.size()` instead. The reason is that `input.c_str()` returns a pointer, and the size of a pointer is not the size of the string that it points to. BTW: sizeof is not a function, so you don't need the brackets here. They are required for the form `sizeof (int)` though.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I changet that. But, sadly, it still doesn't solve that problem.

Comment: Have you set the same baud rate at each end? Use hyper terminal or similar software first to test arduino code. Then connect with your c++ program. `qDebug() << "buffer: " << buffer;` is wrong. You are trying to print `buffer` as a string, but it is not null terminated, hence not a string. this could crash your program or print garbage characters in debug window.

Comment: Yes, baud rates are correct. With terminal arduino code seems to work correctly. Also changed that qDebug message converting buffer to string. But still getting trash.

Comment: How about updating your code? Without that this is just guessing. In addition, make sure you check returnvalues of functions for errors.

Comment: Edited and solved. Thank a lot Ulrich.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - Ulrich was right, but sadly, I edited only one function. My fault.
So problem was really in sizeof(input.c_str()), after changed it everywhere to input.size() it works.